# Why $(A/B) / (A/B)^2$ is isomorphic to $A/ (A^2 + B)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $A,B$ are ideals of certain ring $R$,
Why $(A/B) / (A/B)^2$ is isomorphic to $A/ (A^2 + B)$ ?
I know isomorphism theorem of modules,
$(A/B)/(C/B)$ is isomorphic to $A/C$ and $(A +B)/A$ is isomorphic to $B/(A∩B)$.
I want to know how to apply these isomorphisms theorems to the titled case.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Aren't they rather rings?

Comment: What does the module $(A/B)^2$ mean?  There isn't a "multiplication" for modules.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I edited.

Comment: There is a slight abuse of notation here.  Without $A\supseteq B$, $A/B$ doesn't really make sense and it really should be $(A+B)/B\lhd R/B$ and similarly $(A/B)^2$ is $(A+B)(A+B)/B=(A^2+B)/B\lhd R/B$.

Comment: Why $(A/B)^2＝(A +B)(A +B)/B$? the denominator is why not $B^2$?